# Is there a way to execute code in the debug console from a VSCode extension? (Python)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to create a VSCode extension that can execute some snippets of Python code in the debug console and then follow that up by executing some other commands with the VSCode API such as opening files.

I have gotten as far as:

```
let sendCode = vscode.commands.registerCommand('custom_extension.sendCode', () => {
    vscode.debug.activeDebugConsole.appendLine("print('hello')");
});
context.subscriptions.push(sendCode);
```

Which will just print the text "print('hello')" like below:

[image]

Which is not the behavior I am trying to achieve but I can't find any other methods on `vscode.debug.activeDebugConsole` or `vscode.debug.activeDebugSession` that seem to allow me to execute code.

Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is possible?

Comment: you put some text in the output area of the debug console, that will never execute, you need to get it in the input line at the bottom

Comment: Yeah, any ideas on how to get it into the input line?